# php code to execute inside syntax highlighter

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I'm using the plugin insert_php for wordpress to insert php tags in my pages.  To use that, I wrap my php code with `[insert_php][/insert_php]`.

Recently I installed Syntax Highlighter Evolved to highlight code snippets that I post. To highlight code with this plugin, one wraps the code with `[code][/code]`.

Now I would like to do some calculations based on user input with php, and I would like the output of that to go inside the highlighter. Apparently the simplest case of this will involve something like

```
[code]
[insert_php]

[/insert_php]
[/code]
```

Which doesn't seem to work actually. Is this normal? Have you tried this before? How can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance. If you require any additional information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `[insert_php]` is a shortcode that `eval()`'s the code in the tags as PHP. If that's the case, then your template should be wrapping the result of the PHP execution in `do_shortcode` so that your `[code]` shortcode will format the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm sorry I don't understand what I should do  exactly. Could you elaborate on how to resolve this?

Comment: Need more information on what you are trying to do. Have you written anything in your `functions.php` file?

Comment: Nope. I just installed the plugins. They work separately, but when I nest them in the way I showed in my question they don't work anymore. As I explained in my question, I need to evaluate php code inside the [code] tag.

Comment: Open up `wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php` and replace `add_filter( 'the_content', 'will_bontrager_insert_php', 9 );` with `add_filter( 'the_content', 'will_bontrager_insert_php', 6 );` - it looks like the filter priorities were wrong... if that doesn't work, then you may need to hire a dev to look into it more than what I can help with.

Comment: Doesn't work... I was hoping someone would test it in their own website and tell me how to fix it! It's a generic thing...